# CUPS Error Printer is not Responding

Tags: ubuntu, cups, printer

I've purchased **generic USB POS Receipt Printer** and on supplied mini CDROM I've got driver installation scripts (binary) for **32bit** and **64bit Linux**. Since I am working on **64bit Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS** with **CUPS version 1.7.2** and **kernel version 3.19.0-47-generic #53~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 16:09:14 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux** I've installed driver installation script for **64bit** system. Script executed without errors and it basically installed printer in `CUPS` and here is printer's status in it:[image: POS58PrinterStatus].
Now, if I navigate in `CUPS` to `Print Test Page` and click on `Print Test Page` button, I first get status messages in following order:

1. Rendering completed.
2. Connecting to printer.
3. The printer is not responding.

Here is a screenshot of the situation:
[image: Printer is not responding]
However if I bypass `CUPS` and execute from terminal the following code, for example:
`sudo echo "Test from terminal" > /dev/usb/lp0`
the string `Test from terminal` is printed out, which means cables
are ok and printer connection is also ok. Here is also output of script installation:

```
---------------------------------------

Models included:
                 POS80
                 POS58

Searching for ServerRoot, ServerBin, and DataDir tags in /etc/cups/cupsd.conf

ServerBin tag not present in cupsd.conf - using default

DataDir tag not present in cupsd.conf - using default

ServerRoot = 
ServerBin  = 
DataDir    = 

Copying rastertozj58 filter to /usr/lib/cups/filter

Copying model ppd files to /usr/share/cups/model/zjiang

Add the POS58 printer

Restarting CUPS
 * Stopping Common Unix Printing System cupsd                                                                                                                                                           [ OK ] 
 * Starting Common Unix Printing System cupsd                                                                                                                                                           [ OK ] 

Install Complete
Go to http://localhost:631, or http://127.0.0.1:631 to manage your printer please!
```

Now, I've changed `LogLevel` to `debug` in `cupsd.conf` via `sudo nano /etc/cups/cupsd.conf` and restarted `cups` via `sudo service cups restart` and [here](http://pastebin.com/8dXnf1MX) is output of `/var/log/cups/error_log` when I tried to print something.
What did I miss in `CUPS` settings?

P.S.: I was forced to move `cups` debug output to pastebin since it was to long for my post.

Comment: I'd first check and see what files the installation installed. If you can include at least a description of them in your question, that would be helpful.

Comment: @FaheemMitha hmm the installation script is in binary mode (executable file), not shell script, do you think screenshot of reinstallation would have helped?

Comment: If there is an uninstall option, you could put the relevant directories under version control, and then see what changed. Another option (probably harder) is to trace the binary to see what files it is writing to.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I've upgraded the question with install output.

Comment: You can increase the verbosity of CUPS by replacing "LogLevel ..." by "LogLevel debug" in /etc/cups/cupsd.conf. By experience, I can tell that sometimes CUPS error messages are vague and misleading. I once had a "filter failed" error because colord was not installed for example.

Comment: @Igeorget I've added `cups` output in debug level to question.

Comment: I think the next thing to do is take a log at the log files in `/var/log/cups`, particularly `error_log.*`.

Comment: Excellently written and thorough question, by the way.

Comment: Also check `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/syslog` in case any relevant messages have been output there.

Comment: See http://linux.debian.user.narkive.com/UdDtDc3W/brainydeal-receipt-printer which is useful and probably relevant. In particular, you are using a socket connection. As that thread observes, this is almost certainly wrong. "A socket connection is for a printer which is accessed over the network. Your printer is not networked; it has a direct USB connection to the computer. The device you have used is incorrect - which makes printing impossible." Change it to `usb://`.

Comment: Have you tried a solution similar to this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1867260? i.e. Remove your printer in the web interface and add it again with the printer address field  filled in manually? I find it strange that you have to use the IPP protocol for a local printer. You could probably use something like `lpd:///dev/usb/lp0`

Comment: @FaheemMitha I should have refreshed my page before posting my comment, my solution is the same as yours only 11 mins later :-)

Comment: @lgeorget Great minds think alike. :-)

Comment: Same thread via gmane: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.debian.user/482204

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Brainydeal Receipt Printer](http://linux.debian.user.narkive.com/UdDtDc3W/brainydeal-receipt-printer) (alternatively [Brainydeal Receipt Printer](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.debian.user/482204)) which is useful and probably relevant.

In particular, you are using a socket connection. As that thread observes, this is almost certainly wrong.

> A socket connection is for a printer which is accessed over the
>   network. Your printer is not networked; it has a direct USB connection
>   to the computer. The device you have used is incorrect - which makes
>   printing impossible.

Change it to `usb://`. That same thread helpfully has a suggestion on how to do this using the web interface:

> The device needs to be changed. One way is:
>
> 1. Reboot the computer with the printer attached and switched on.
> 2. Go to http://localhost:631 with your browser.
> 3. Go to "Administration". Is the printer found?
> 4. Proceed to install a print queue with the PPD in the zjiang directory.

To be clear, you can install a new "software" printer. You don't even need to delete the current entry, and don't do so till you get a new one working, in case you need it for reference.

Another way to do this is via lpadmin. See `man lpadmin`.

Comment: how do I compose `usb` connection string?

Comment: See above. The relevant string should show up in the web interface. You could also try `lpstat -t`.

Comment: @KernelPanic Please add your comment as a comment, not as an edit to the answer. Did you find the URI via the web interface, or did you just make it up?

Comment: why would I make it up? Here is info listing from CUPS Printer Settings web interface:
`Description: POS58
Location: Kitchen
Driver: POS58 (grayscale, 2-sided printing)
Connection: usb://Unknown/Printer
Defaults: job-sheets=none, none media=om_x58mm-y210mm_57.86x209.9mm sides=one-sided`

Comment: @KernelPanic Ok, noted.